# iPhone Parsing JSON : delegate methods

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, methods, delegates

I'm using [this JSON framework](http://github.com/stig/json-framework). It's working well but I would like to put a loading view on my main screen to show that the iphone is downloading datas. I have searched for some delegate methode like - jsonBeginParse and - jsonEndParse but unsuccessfully.

Have got an idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you want to show a loading item when its parsing or when its downloading JSON from a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the implementation files are available, you can implement that by yourself, either using a delegate, or simply by using the [notification](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) system.